# Need to get maximum date range which is overlapping in SQL

Tags: sql, date, impala

I have a table with 3 columns id, start_date, end_date

Some of the values are as follows:

```
1   2018-01-01  2030-01-01 
1   2017-10-01  2018-10-01 
1   2019-01-01  2020-01-01 
1   2015-01-01  2016-01-01
2   2010-01-01  2011-02-01 
2   2010-10-01  2010-12-01
2   2008-01-01  2009-01-01
```

I have the above kind of data set where I have to filter out overlap date range by keeping maximum datarange and keep the other date range which is not overlapping for a particular id.

Hence desired output should be:

```
1   2018-01-01  2030-01-01 
1   2015-01-01  2016-01-01
2   2010-01-01  2011-02-01 
2   2008-01-01  2009-01-01
```

I am unable to find the right way to code in impala. Can someone please help me.

I have tried like,

```
with cte as(
   select a*, row_number() over(partition by id order by datediff(end_date , start_date) desc) as flag from mytable a) select * from cte where flag=1
```

but this will remove other date range which is not overlapping. Please help.

Comment: And if you are using Impala, why have you tagged SQL Server? Completely different RDBMS unless I am mistaken?

Comment: Shouldn't the output also contain 2017-2018 ?

Comment: No  @SaiPatil, it overlap max date range,2018-01-01  2030-01-01 will be taken

Comment: i have tried , some row number partition way which i just post above, but unble to find my desired output. can someone please guide me or help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use row number with countItem for each id

```
with cte as(
   select *,
       row_number() over(partition by id order by id) as seq,
       count(*) over(partition by id order by id) as countItem
   from mytable
)
select id,start_date,end_date
from cte
where seq = 1 or seq = countItem
```

or without cte

```
select id,start_date,end_date
from
    (select *,
       row_number() over(partition by id order by id) as seq,
       count(*) over(partition by id order by id) as countItem
     from mytable) t
where seq = 1 or seq = countItem
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=861bbf200a5cfb757e59b23500ea054d)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cumulative max to see if there is any overlap with preceding rows.  If there is not, then you have the first row of a new group (row in the result set).

A cumulative sum of the starts assigns each row in the source to a group.  Then aggregate:

```
select id, min(start_date), max(end_date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_end_date >= start_date then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (partition by id
                  order by start_date
                  rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                 ) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   max(end_date) over (partition by id
                                       order by start_date
                                       rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                      ) as prev_end_date
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
group by id, grp;
```